# Trouble with onload and collecting field information in IE. Fine in Chrome

Tags: html, onload, window.location

In the body I have the following:

```
<body onload="loadCheck1();">
```

Which points to the following function:

```
function loadCheck1() {

var chkme1 = "<?php echo $_GET['update']; ?>";
if (chkme1 ==1){
window.location = "viewrecipe.php?recipe_name="+recipe_name.value+"&update=2&texty1="+texty1.value+"&texty2="+texty2.value+"&texty3="+texty3.value+"&texty4="+texty4.value+"&texty5="+texty5.value; 
}

if (last==3){
window.location = "viewrecipe.php?recipe_name="+recipe_name.value+"&NewFG1="+texty4.value+"&NewAlc="+texty5.value;
}

}
```

The URL being `viewrecipe.php?update=1` should load the first window.location and `viewrecipe.php?update=3` should load the 2nd.

In Chrome this works absolutely fine. In IE I get an error saying "recipe_name" undefined.

The only thing I can think of is that in Chrome the code only activates after the actual loading of the page. As by that time all the field values will be filled in.

Is there an alternative method to running a function once the page has loaded?

Answer (score 0):

There are several variables not defined in your function:
 - recipe_name
 - last

Are they defined somewhere else?
I guess that texty1 to texty5 are form inputs. If not these variables are not defined too.

You should give us more of your code so we can help you.